# Facing Auto Augmentation Problem in YOLO-NAS

Tags: python, data-augmentation, yolonas

I have trained a YOLO-NAS L model for some Pavement markings like Crossmarks, Left arrow, Right arrow, Bike lane, Junction etc. While testing the model on Unseen data the right and left arrow is getting confused. Most right arrow is been identified as Left and vice versa.** So if there is some internal Flipping or other augmentation are there, where can I find that, and I want to remove all auto augmentations**

It would be helpful if you can find the script or part where I can stop the auto augmentation.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.